# Why if I extend the App trait in Scala, I override the main method?

Tags: scala

So I read that the App trait has the following fields:

```
def delayedInit(body: ⇒ Unit): Unit

val executionStart: Long

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit
```

I know that if a trait only has one method, by "putting code" between the curly braces in the class declaration I am overriding that. But here I have two methods. So why am I overriding automatically main and not delayedInit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not overriding `main` method.

Since `App` extends [`DelayedInit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.DelayedInit) compiler rewrites your code like this:

```
// Before:
object Test extends App {
  println("test")
}

// After:
object Test extends App {
  delayedInit{println("test")}
}
```

From `DelayedInit` [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.DelayedInit):

> Classes and objects (but note, not traits) inheriting the
>   `DelayedInit` marker trait will have their initialization code
>   rewritten as follows: `code` becomes `delayedInit(code)`.

`App` trait [implements](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/App.scala#L59) `delayedInit` like this:

```
override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) {
  initCode += (() => body)
}
```

So in `Test` object constructor code `println("test")` is stored as function (`() => Unit`) in `initCode` field.

`main` method of `App` is implemented as call for all functions stored in `initCode` field:

```
for (proc <- initCode) proc()
```