# scala App class DelayedInit hook

Tags: scala

```
  trait App extends DelayedInit {
  //...
  private val initCode = new ListBuffer[() => Unit]

  /** The init hook. This saves all initialization code for execution within `main`.
   *  This method is normally never called directly from user code.
   *  Instead it is called as compiler-generated code for those classes and objects
   *  (but not traits) that inherit from the `DelayedInit` trait and that do not
   *  themselves define a `delayedInit` method.
   *  @param body the initialization code to be stored for later execution
   */
  override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) {
    initCode += (() => body)
  }
  //...
}

object CircuitMain extends App {
  // You can write tests either here, or better in the test class CircuitSuite.
  Circuit.andGateExample //line in question ?
}
```

[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808747/why-if-i-extend-the-app-trait-in-scala-i-override-the-main-method)  why-if-i-extend-the-app-trait-in-scala-i-override-the-main-method

I can see that in the comment it is saying it will be called by compiler generated code.
and from the related post, it is saying that the scala compiler will do special things about **DelayedInit**, what made this **DelayedInit** trait so special ? is it language related feature? or we can do similar things to other traits as well ?  if yes, how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was pondering this myself the other day...

Yes, it's a language specific feature - check Section 5.1 "Delayed Initializaton" in the Scala Language Specification:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

You can also confirm this checking out the compiler source code:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/946b76ad8b31b1fd74e2f8e1972c4a9159ac690a/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/StdNames.scala

```
// Compiler utilized names
...
val delayedInit: NameType          = "delayedInit"
val delayedInitArg: NameType       = "delayedInit$body"
```

And also:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/96df73d994097e3318d003ddef00194b711289a3/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Definitions.scala

```
// classes with special meanings
lazy val StringAddClass             = requiredClass[scala.runtime.StringAdd]
lazy val ScalaNumberClass           = requiredClass[scala.math.ScalaNumber]
lazy val TraitSetterAnnotationClass = requiredClass[scala.runtime.TraitSetter]
lazy val DelayedInitClass           = requiredClass[scala.DelayedInit]
  def delayedInitMethod = getMemberMethod(DelayedInitClass, nme.delayedInit)
```