# Why we need lazy evaluation by extending App trait in Scala?

Tags: scala

Now i understand how my program runs after extending App trait .[I went through this link to understand how App trait works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808747/why-if-i-extend-the-app-trait-in-scala-i-override-the-main-method) . In the link it is mentioned that by extending App trait we are achieving lazy evaluation . Why i would need lazy evaluation ?  How lazy evaluation better than direct call to main() instead of extending App trait ?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's the other way around: we don't need lazy eval, but we use it behind the scenes because that's the only way to implement it. From the [scaladoc](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/App.scala#L38):

> The `App` trait can be used to quickly turn objects into executable
>   programs.

By using `App` trait you avoid the boilerplate of writing:

```
object MainApp { 
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { ... }
}
```

There is no way to achieve this syntax: `object MainApp extends App {...}` with regular means because you would have to override `main` method to call your code. Thus you can use compiler trick with `DelayedInit` which will turn your object body into a function call which will be called from main - this is the way to connect your code to the main entry point.

The caveat mentioned by scaladoc is:

> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the
>   [[DelayedInit]]  functionality, which means that fields of the object
>   will not have been initialized before the main method has been
>   executed.

which for me personally is a preferred way of doing things. This, in contrast, is different from static initializers in Java that are executed before `main` method is called.

Comment: Thanks for the simple way of explanation . I am astonished that it is only to write code faster !!!